# Why not bend the knees in Alenu?

Tags: minhag, bowing-kneeling, aleinu-leshabeiach

[This OU source](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/waist-bowing-and-knee-bowing/) and [dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2017/09/28/kneeling-and-prostration-laws-and-customs/) say to bow at the waist in Alenu starting with the phrase "ve'anachnu kore'im" but not to bend the knees. Why not bend the knees for this phrase, given that it means just that?

Comment: both answers at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37464/759 disagree with your source fwiw

Comment: Your dinonline source doesn't seem to say anything relevant. It's primarily discussing bowing to the floor

Comment: @DoubleAA I refer you to the part that ways "While in our daily recitation of Aleinu we bow only the upper part of our bodies".

Comment: That is clearly irrelevant since in context it is just in contrast to the high holidays when the whole body bends down. It doesn't mention if the knees should be bent or not while bowing the upper part of the body. It doesn't detail the daily bowing at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA "Clearly irrelevant" is not clear to me. "Only upper body" seems to rule out knees.